# Do NOT want to get nested group results in active directory search

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ou

I am trying to interogate active directory and add the contents in a dropdown list. I have been succesfull so far, but my only issue is I am getting the nested groups from my search base and filter below and I do not want this to happen.  How do I NOT get nested groups results from my code below?

```
var searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
var searchBase = "ou=Apps,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx";
```

Many thanks,
George

Comment: Can you provide us an extract of the directory you're searching, an example of the result of the search and what you want to obtain?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed this now.  I had the search scope set wrong and should have set it to ONELEVEL_SCOPE.